# How to upgrade npm after upgrading node.js via binary archive

Tags: node.js, npm

We have upgraded our node.js from version 12 to 16 (on OEL 7.9) using binary archive steps (https://github.com/nodejs/help/wiki/Installation#how-to-install-nodejs-via-binary-archive-on-linux).

Node.js was upgraded to version 16 but NPM is not. Can you help me or provide steps on how to install npm. Note that we are using binary archive steps as upgrading package manager or NVM is not working due to security on our linux servers.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWv5a.png)
This warning is showing when we login to server.
Notice that node.js is already upgraded to version 16 but NPM is not. NPM should be version 8.
Please advise. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `npm update -g npm` or `npm install -g npm`?

Comment: Not working on our machines that is why we are upgrading using binary archive.
This is the error using upgrade/install commands for both node.js and npm.

Loaded plugins: langpacks, rhnplugin 
This system is receiving updates from Spacewalk server . 
No Match for argument: npm 
No package npm available . 
No packages marked for update